# conflict dojo.require and Socket.io client

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, socket.io

I use `dojo 1.8.6` and `socket.io  0.9.16`, after I load `socket.io.js client`, `dojo.require` conflict is happened and no more dojo module can load.

`require([ 'socket.io/socket.io' ])` cause error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I can't use "dojox/socket" for some reason.

Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

As of dojo 1.11 the following is working fine:

```
packages: [
    "dojo",
    {name: "socketio", location: "/socket.io", main: "socket.io"}
]
```

with module loading:

```
define([
    "socketio"
], function (socketio) { 
    var socket = socketio();
});
```

I assume its working in prior versions as well but i have not tested it.

Alternatively you could directly refer to the socket.io module as it is AMD compliant.

```
define([
    "/socket.io/socket.io.js"
], function (socketio) { 
    var socket = socketio();
});
```

Unfortunately the builder does still report an 311 error (missing dependency) hence not breaking the build. Can't work around this as there is no package.js where to mark as copy only...

Answer (score 0):

The require statement needs to be a valid AMD mid (module identifier).

Usually, people will add the package to their config, e.g.:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    packages: [
        {name: 'socketio', location: 'path/to/socket.io/socket.io'}
    ]
}
```

and then require it:

```
require(['socketio'], function (socketio) {
    // do something with socketio
});
```

As far as why you cannot use dojox/socket, I don't see any code to comment on. You might also want to check out https://github.com/bryanforbes/tube , which is a draft of a replacement for dojox/socket.

Comment: i add new project on github [link]https://github.com/ooghry/dojo-socketio can you edit those code,tnx.  
i try to connect to `node.js` server via `dojox/socket` but this module only accept `ws://` and `wss://`, but my server run over http,i know it's weird.i really want use socketio.